# PHP :Fatal error using fwrite to append one file to the end of another

Tags: php

Hey Im trying to append one file to the end of another and then display to screen and have looked for a solution to my error and have been unsuccessful. The code below does work to add info from the second file onto the end of the other but will not display on screen and gives me a fatal error on line 13 , any help/guidance would be appreciated! Cheers.

```
<?php
        $file1 = fopen("lab5.1", "a+") or exit("Unable to open file1!");
        $file2 =fopen("lab5.2", "r+") or exit("Unable to open file2!");

        while(!feof($file1)){
            fwrite($file1 , fread($file2,100));
        }

        fclose($file1);//close and reopen added to try solve fatal error
        $file1 = fopen("lab5.1", "r") or exit("Unable to open file1!");

        while(!feof($file1))
        {
            echo fgets($file1). "<br>";
        }

        fclose($file1);
        fclose($file2);

    ?>
```

Comment: in th first while(), why are you testing for eof on file1? That's the file you're writing **TOO**. Since you opened it for appending, by definition you're already AT THE END. You should be checking for eof on the file2, which is what you're reading FROM.

Comment: oh that fixed it , apologies for such a basic question I was searching for a fix and couldn't find one  ! Cheers Marc!